# Dynamic DIV elements on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario in which I need to show a DIV element on a button click and if the user clicks on the button again I need to show the same DIV element twice and so on as many times the user clicks on the button. The below is the DIV element

```
                <div class="input-group" id="selection">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" >

                   <option>True</option>
                   <option>False</option>

                  </select>
                </div>
```

And the below  is the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" 
              type="button" style="margin-left: 30px;">Add new selection</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use jquery clone and/or append ??

Comment: I'm new to JS and to  be frank I have no idea on how to do this.

Comment: how can I again show an element which is already shown?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I dont wanted to show the same element, but I wanted the element to  be duplicated each and every time a user clicks

Comment: store your div content in a variable JS. If it's the first click (use counter) add the content to your div if it's more than one, create a new div and add the content.

Comment: If you haven't taken the time to research and have your own attempt why should others do it for you? If you don't have time to research and learn then I recommend you hire a developer. You don't have **any** javascript/jQuery here, posting the html is just asking for handouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clone` if you want to have an *exact* copy of the div. in case of any dynamic divs, you can consider using `append` like the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqoezc0c/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.clone()` for this,

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    var div = $(".input-group").last();
    div.after(div.clone());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y544g7qx/6/)

`clone()` will get a copy of the specified element. Then you can use `last() or before()`  to add the element to the dom.

If you have a container for this div elements, then you can use `append()` as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying something like this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<select class='show-tick'><option>True</option><option>False</option></select><br>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ol>
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" >

                   <option>True</option>
                   <option>False</option>

                  </select>
                </div>
</ol>

<button id="btn">Append list item</button>

</body>
</html>
```